# Is there any way to prepend a string to the beginning of a couch doc ID? Ie. "article_<regular random ID here>"

Tags: couchdb

Title pretty much explains my problem. If this isn't possible, how can I write my own IDs? Specifically, how do I generate an ID string that I know isn't currently taken by Couch then I can do the string append myself and save it.

Comment: CouchDB can generate UUIDs for you by [sending a GET request to `/_uuids`](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HttpGetUuids). However obtaining unique `_id`s is heavily application dependant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [update handler](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Handlers) to combine a prefix of your choosing and an automatically generated UUID. An update handler basically intercepts an HTTP request, does some additional transformation and returns the new document. (and a message to be sent in response to the user)

In an update handler, the `req` object is also given the UUID that CouchDB would have assigned to the document. If there is no existing document for the current request, you can create a new one entirely from scratch.

```
function (doc, req) {
    // if no document exists
    if (!doc) {
        // create a new one
        doc = {
            // req.id is the generated UUID for this request
            _id: "article_" + req.id
        }; 
    }

    // always return an array 1) the new doc and 2) the string response message
    return [ doc, "New Article Created" ];
}
```

The example here is really trivial, and more complete examples are given in that wiki page that I linked to. I just wanted to show you nothing more than what you needed for your question. Update handlers are a very powerful way to implement some application logic at the database layer.

Comment: Is it `req.id` or `req.uuid`? I can't recall.

Comment: Not sure, tbh, that's how the wiki puts it. I'll probably go amend the page if I can verify the correct answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

I prefer Dominic's answer but for completeness, you could also pre-load a bunch of UUIDs from  CouchDB and combine them yourself. To get a batch of five:

```
$ curl -i example.iriscouch.com/_uuids?count=5
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: CouchDB/1.2.0 (Erlang OTP/R15B)
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
ETag: "86908CQ9GCBC01P6VF18YM2P4"
Date: Sun, 12 Feb 2012 02:03:23 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 187
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, no-cache
Connection: keep-alive

{"uuids":["da769daee5996412c8f598155c002885","da769daee5996412c8f598155c0034b4","da769daee5996412c8f598155c00406f","da769daee5996412c8f598155c004c18","da769daee5996412c8f598155c00501a"]}
```

Now you can compose your own IDs. You have more work ahead of you, to write and maintain the code to do all this. But the advantage is that you do not need an update function, executing a Javascript function (and potentially spawning a Javascript process on the server) for every document update.

Personally, I would start with Dominique's technique and only move to mine if/when you hit performance problems.